# How to inject Javascript in a QWebFrame?

Tags: qt, qwebkit

```
QObject::connect(webview->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(initialLayoutCompleted()), webview->page()->mainFrame(), SLOT(evaluateJavaScript("alert(); null")));
```

My code can be compiled but then happens nothing. evaluateJavascript is not the problem, because I have tested in standalone and it works fine. The signal is neither the problem, because I have done:

```
QObject::connect(webview->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(initialLayoutCompleted()), webview, SLOT(close())));
```

And the app is closed properly. I think that the problem is related with the "webview->page->mainFrame()" part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`evaluateJavaScript("alert(); null")` is not the name of a slot, it's a fully formed function call. The `QObject:connect()` fails because it expects the name of a slot, including the argument types, not a function call.

You need to provide your own slot function here, inside a class of yours, possibly inheriting  QWebView. Then put that `evaluateJavascript("...")` call inside that slot and connect `SIGNAL(initialLayoutCompleted())` to it.